# Magento 2. What are price adjustments?

Tags: magento2, price

In price calculating process I often see something called adjustments.

```
Magento\Framework\Pricing\Adjustment\AdjustmentInterface
```

What are adjustments and how do they work?

Answer (score 0):

It is classes which use

```
\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Adjustment\AdjustmentInterface
```

Adjustment uses for additional calculations for product price f.e taxes.
You can implement own taxesl, using the interface, and make addititional calculations.